# Hyper-V - 'VM name' failed to start on Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v

I have a VM on Azure:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- VS 2015 Community Update 2 (with Xamarin)

When I build an Android application (directly after creation with the template) I have this error:

```
[Window Title]
Hyper-V Manager

[Main Instruction]
An error occurred while attempting to start the selected virtual machine(s).

[Content]
'VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' failed to start.

Failed to start the virtual machine 'VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.

[Expanded Information]
'VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' failed to start. (Virtual machine ID F03A58D7-BEAB-4FA2-A17F-FACC465E8559)

The Virtual Machine Management Service failed to start the virtual machine 'VS Emulator 5-inch KitKat (4.4) XXHDPI Phone' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running (Virtual machine ID F03A58D7-BEAB-4FA2-A17F-FACC465E8559).

[V] See details  [Close]
```

An idea ?
Thx

Comment: Have you tried using Xamarin Android Player instead? https://www.xamarin.com/android-player

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately this won't work because Azure doesn't support nested virtualisation.

Nested virtualisation is needed because Azure already runs in a virtual machine, in order to run a virtualised instance inside that instance you would need to have the appropriate flags enabled in the host machine. Azure does not enable those flags across its infrastructure (and neither do any of the other major cloud vendors)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
Just for me, what are the flags to change to allow nested virtualisation ?

Comment: There are a bunch of them by now! have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization)

Answer (score 0):

### * Open the .vmx file in notepad and ad the following lines:

```
hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"
mce.enable = "TRUE"
vhu.enable = "TRUE"
```

---

- Run the VM.
- Go to "Programs and Features" and ensure that Hyper-V is installed

Comment: vmx file is only for VMware, right ? On my Azure VM, I don't find any vmx file (with the Windows search)

Comment: I made your mentioned changes, but still it didn't work for my VMware machine. Is there something else to do?